# How to Run Magento 1.9 Api from Javascript

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap

I want to run Magento Apis using JavaScript and person certain functions such: get all orders, get specific order, create shipment etc,

Now I have seen other tutorials and i can run Magento Apis through PHP. but i haven't found a much things on running Apis through JS or other languages other than PHP. is there any way.

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

The Magento API supports [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) and [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_RPC), where SOAP is the default protocol.

You can do this using Magentos XML-RPC.

To use XML-RPC, load the following URL into your XML-RPC client:

```
http://magentohost/api/xmlrpc/
```

> Reference Examples:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.xmlrpc.js"></script>
```

You can get jQuery XML-RPC library from here:

[jQuery XML-RPC library](http://jquery-xml-rpc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)

> Login Call for Session token

```
$.xmlrpc({
    url: 'Your_magento_root/index.php/api/xmlrpc',
    methodName: 'login',
    params: ['api_user', "api_key"],
    success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
        alert('Sucsses');       
        Session = response[0]; // this session key is important for next transaction                 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        alert('error');
        console.log(status);  
    }
});
```

> After Login Calls

```
$.xmlrpc({
    url: 'Your_magento_root/index.php/api/xmlrpc',
    methodName: 'call',
    params: [Session, 'Your_methode_name',[0,'any other parameter',1]],
    success: function(response, status, jqXHR) {
        alert('Sucsses');
        var data = response[0];  // Here is your data.
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        alert('error-inside');
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```

Reference Doc:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/introduction.html

**I hope this will help**

Comment: getting this error in browser 

_m1-test.html:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.host.com/index.php/api/xmlrpc' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request._

Comment: This is not working, if you know the way around. Kindly tell.

Comment: Hi Hasham, can you help me on  this